# Value doesnot show in datagridview when date selected in datetimepicker

Tags: c#, datagridview

When i choose From Date and Todate from datetimepicker to show data in datagridview at that time datagridview show me empty data , code is written button click evet, here im using access database

```
DateTime startT = new DateTime();
                DateTime endT = new DateTime();
                startT = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
                endT = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
                if (startT.Date > endT.Date)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("To Date Cannot be greater than Start Date");
                }
                else
                {
                    string connetionString = null;
                    connetionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                    con.ConnectionString = connetionString;

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    string sql = "SELECT Medicine_name,sum(Medicine_count) as Medicine_count,To_Date from Medicine_count_info where [To_Date] Between #" + startT.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy") + "#And #" + endT.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy") + "#group by Medicine_name,Medicine_count,To_Date order by Medicine_count desc ";
                    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
                    OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
                    ds = new DataSet();
                    connection.Open();
                    dataadapter.Fill(ds);
                    connection.Close();
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
                    dataGridView1.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName;
                    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If `To_Date` is a date column you dont need to torture the date range like that.  Use SQL parameters and just pass a date.  You should also be disposing of the connection and command objects...and if you held onto the DataTAble, you could just apply a Filter to it rather than run a while new query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in your select you are missing a space in `"#And #"`

Also,assuming [To_Date] is a datetime field, the problem is probably how you are building your select clause passing the data as string. Use DateTime fields instead and, of course ALWAYS USE PARAMETRIZED QUERIES. Something like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT Medicine_name,sum(Medicine_count) as Medicine_count,To_Date " +
"FROM Medicine_count_info " +
"WHERE [To_Date] Between @startDate And @endDate " +
"GROUP BY Medicine_name,Medicine_count,To_Date " +
"ORDER BY Medicine_count desc ";
OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
dataadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", startT);
dataadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", endT);
ds = new DataSet();
dataadapter.Fill(ds);
...
```

Comment: sir its working perfectly fine thnx for suggestion and help :)